# on_the_spot gem not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I have just installed the "on_the_spot" gem following the github instructions.

And I'm trying to create a in-place edit for my index action. When I get the mouse over the text that should be editable, nothing happens. Only the background color changes.

This is the relevant code from my index view

```
<% @part_types.each do |part_type| %>
<tr>
  <td><%= on_the_spot_edit part_type, :title %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

From the controller:

```
class PartTypesController < ApplicationController

#on_the_spot for in place editing
can_edit_on_the_spot
#.. rest of the controller code
end
```

Added to the routes:

```
resources :part_types do
  collection do
    put :update_attribute_on_the_spot
  end
end
```

nginx already restarted after these changes.

Thank you

Comment: Solved. I have removed some javascript files. Just loading jquery.js, application.js and the "on_the_spot" js created files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your Gemfile add the following:

gem "on_the_spot"
Run the installation task:

rails g on_the_spot:install

if u using rails 3.1 replace created files to app/assets/javascripts (two files jquery.jeditable.mini and on_the_spot)